# Rails Factory Girl: How to setup has_many/through association with other model being created from nested attributes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, factory-bot, nested-attributes

I've been struggling with setting up a has_many/through relationship when one model object is being created through nested attributes using Factory Girl.

```
class CommercialInvoice < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :shipment_commercial_invoices, :dependent => :destroy
  has_many :shipments, :through => :shipment_commercial_invoices
end

class Shipment < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :shipment_commercial_invoices, :dependent => :destroy
  has_many :commercial_invoices, :through => :shipment_commercial_invoices
end

class ShipmentCommercialInvoices < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :job_id, :detail_id
  belongs_to :shipment
  belongs_to :commercial_invoice
end
```

The Shipment model is created using nested attributes inside another model supplier_invoice

```
class SupplierInvoice < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :shipments, :dependent => :destroy
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :shipments, :allow_destroy => true
end

class Shipment < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :supplier_invoice
end
```

My Factories

```
factory :supplier_invoice do do
  shipments_attributes do        
    shipments_attributes = []
    2.times do # 2 shipments per supplier invoice
      shipments_attributes << attributes_with_foreign_keys(:shipment)
    end
    shipments_attributes
  end
end

factory :commercial_invoice do
  after(:create) do |commercial_invoice, evaluator|
      commercial_invoice.shipments << FactoryGirl.create(:supplier_invoice).shipments
  end
end

factory :shipments_commercial_invoice do
  shipment
  commercial_invoice
  comm_invoiced true # A boolean attribute that i want to be true
end
```

Now the problem in whenever i create a new commercial invoice, the associated shipment_commercial_invoice's attribute **comm_invoiced is always false**. I am not able to figure out what am i doing wrong. Is there any problem with how i defined factories? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't know if this is the solution, but you definitely have a syntax error here: ```factory :supplier_invoice do do```.

Comment: You are right @Daniel. Made an error while copying my code.

Comment: So is my answer the correct one?

Comment: I am sorry but No. That's a typo i made while copying my code here. I'll edit my question.

Comment: Any solution found @akshay?